# Read input in reverse order

Tags: c

I am new to C. I have just learned pointers and `struct`.I am trying to modify the following program so that each student read is inserted at the front of the list of students, not at the end. How can I achieve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 80      // The longest line this program will accept
#define MAX_NUM_STUDENTS 500    // The maximum number of students this program can handle
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 50        // The maximum allowable name length
typedef struct student_s Student;

struct student_s {
    char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    int age;
    Student* next;              // Pointer to next student in a list
};
Student studentPool[MAX_NUM_STUDENTS];  // The student pool
int firstFree = 0;
Student* newStudent(const char* name, int age)
{
    Student* student = NULL;
    if (firstFree < MAX_NUM_STUDENTS) {
        student = &studentPool[firstFree];
        firstFree += 1;
        strncpy(student->name, name, MAX_NAME_SIZE);
        student->name[MAX_NAME_SIZE - 1] = '\0';  // Make sure it's terminated
        student->age = age;
        student->next = NULL;
    }
    return student;
}
Student* readOneStudent(FILE* file)
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];  // Buffer into which we read a line from stdin
    Student* student = NULL;       // Pointer to a student record from the pool

    // Read a line, extract name and age

    char* inputLine = fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file);
    if (inputLine != NULL) {        // Proceed only if we read something
        char* commaPos = strchr(buffer, ',');
        if (commaPos != NULL) {
            int age = atoi(commaPos + 1);
            *commaPos = '\0';  // null-terminate the name
            student = newStudent(buffer, age);
        }
    }
    return student;
}
Student* readStudents(FILE *file)
{
    Student* first = NULL;     // Pointer to the first student in the list
    Student* last = NULL;      // Pointer to the last student in the list
    Student* student = readOneStudent(file);
    while (student != NULL) {
        if (first == NULL) {
            first = last = student;   // Empty list case
        } else {
            last->next = student;
            last = student;
        }
        student = readOneStudent(file);
    }
    return first;
}
void printOneStudent(Student student)
{
    printf("%s (%d)\n", student.name, student.age);
}
void printStudents(const Student* student)
{
    while (student != NULL) {
        printOneStudent(*student);
        student = student->next;
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    FILE* inputFile = fopen("studlist.txt", "r");
    if (inputFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File not found\n");
    } else {
        Student* studentList = readStudents(inputFile);
        printStudents(studentList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Inserting at the front is usually dead easy.  It’s inserting at the end that’s hard.

Comment: This is surprisingly similar to what any teacher will probably give as second homework to a class for the topic of linked lists. Linked list questions can always be answered by taking pen and paper and drawing boxes and arrows. Please state whether this is a homework assignment and you want help according to the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Why not take a moment to look at the `else` statement in `Student* readStudents(FILE *file)` and ponder what you would need to do to `last->next = student;` and `last = student;` to add at the head of the list instead of the tail?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin has provided the first hint according to the compromise (probably intentionally). Please state whether you want more and are willing to do your part of it.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882857/add-to-front-of-linked-list although that code was in Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently have this code to insert at the end (of a non-empty list):

```
if (first == NULL) {
    first = last = student;   // Empty list case
} else {
    last->next = student;
    last = student;
}
```

To insert at the front of a non-empty list, you simply need to make the new student into the first student each time, by making its `next` pointer point to the current `first` student, and making the `first` pointer point at the new student.

```
if (first == NULL) {
    first = last = student;   // Empty list case
} else {
    student->next = first;
    first = student;
}
```

Draw the boxes; connect them with arrows.  It should become obvious.

---

Also, you could simply use:

```
student->next = first;
first = student;
```

If `first` is null, `student->next` will be (re)set to null, so there's no need for a special case on `first`.  Since `last` was only used within the function for adding to the end of the list, when inserting at the front, there's no need for `last` at all.  These two observations make the code still simpler than the first version proposed.